# How can I retrieve a gitlab issue by its id?

Tags: gitlab-api

I am trying to track a GitLab issue no matter in what project it may reside.

An issue is normally created in GitLab within the context of a project. If it is moved to another project, the issue is closed and a new issue is created. The original issue tracks the new location using the `moved_to_id`. The problem is I have no idea how to follow this `moved_to_id` value using the GitLab API v4. GitLab does not honour the typical REST-like behaviour where you can retrieve an entity by its ID.

For example, if I call `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/issues/` I'll get a list of issues as objects: these objects have a set of fields: title, description, state, ..., `id` and `iid`. The `iid` is the user-friendly id of an issue within a project. But what is the `id` and how is it useful? I can't retrieve an issue using this `id` - at least not using expected ways...

Consider an issue exists in `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/issues/` with `id` == `29564819`,

1. `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/issues/29564819` returns a 404.
2. `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/issues/29564819/` returns a 404.
3. `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/issues/29564819?scope=all` returns a 404
4. `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/issues/?id=29564819` returns all the issues (no effect using parameter).

Can I retrieve an issue without a project? Do I have to resort to using labels?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, I need to list all issues with given `id`s, but there's only `iids[]` parameter, I wonder who designed these APIs... Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: I gave up, to be honest. I was hoping the Internet geniuses or a subject matter expert from GitLab would swoop down and provide an answer :)

Comment: ok, I see, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If a user is not a member of a private project, a GET request on that project results in a 404 status code.

Only administrators can retrieve issue by its id.

The preferred way to do this is by using personal access tokens.

GET /issues/:id

Answer (score 0):

I believe the possible reason is that the API endpoint you mentioned earlier might be restricted to administrators only, as stated in the documentation for [Single Issue](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#single-issue)). In other words, it is suitable for self-hosted GitLab instances.

If that's not the case, you should consider using a slightly different endpoint, [Single Project Issue](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#single-project-issue), specifying the appropriate project ID and issue IID (not an ID).